Using `solve_ivp` and `LSODA` to solve a complex ODE
I am trying to solve a complex system of differential equations. The equations are stiff so I need to need to use a method which can handle both complex ODEs and stiffness switching. I have landed on using odeintw (link) which is able to solve my problem, however I also need to have event handling.
I have tried to solve the problem using solve_ivp and BDF, but the evaluation takes an unreasonable amount of time.
Is there an existing framework, like odeintw which lets me use solve_ivp with the LSODA method to solve complex differential equations? Or is there some way to implement event handling with odeintw?

Is it "complex" in the sense of "extension of the real numbers" or in the sense of "highly structured"? Both are covered by odeintw.

Complex as in complex numbers, i.e., z = x + i y. Both are covered by odeintw, however I would really like to use event  handling which only seems to be possible with solve_ivp

As far as I know, solve_ivp has no problem with complex numbers as state components. Note that the event functions have to return real numbers as values, so that the composition of state and event functions results in a scalar real function.

Using solve_ivp with LSODA and complex initial conditions gives the error: ValueError: 'y0' is complex, but the chosen solver does not support integration in a complex domain. This error doesn't appear if I use BDF, which isn't surprising based on solve_ivp documentation.

If you have to rely on a real-only solver, then you have to provide the wrapper yourself. Define functions R2C and C2R that are inverse to each other and enhance or wrap your ODE and event functions.
def R2C(xy): z = xy[:n]+1j*xy[n:]; return z

def C2R(z): xy = np.concatenate([z.real, z.imag]); return xy

def odefunc(t,xy):
    z = R2C(xy)
    ...
    return C2R(z_dot)

etc.
